# Crash due to unrecognized selector sent to (after first launch only)

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

[image]I have a crash but only the first time I install and run the app.  The crash reason is below:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OnBoardViewController info:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f86f4c1f090'
```

As you can see the selector `info` is not in the class.  Here's the `OnBoardViewController` class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class OnboardViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
@IBOutlet var onBoardView : UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var onBoardViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
@IBOutlet var pageIndicator: UIPageControl!

// MARK: VC lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    onBoardView.delegate = self
    onBoardView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    configureCollectionView()
}

// MARK: UI
func configureCollectionView () {
    onBoardView.isPagingEnabled = true
    onBoardView.bounces = false
    onBoardView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    onBoardViewLayout.itemSize = onBoardView.bounds.size
    onBoardViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    onBoardViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
    onBoardViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}

// MARK: Scroll delegates
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentPage = ceil(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)
    pageIndicator.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}

// MARK: UICollectionView delegates
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "onboardCellID", for: indexPath) as! OnboardCell
    cell.screen = indexPath.item
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

}
```

After this crash, I relaunched the app, it doesn't crash any more.  If I delete the app, install and launch it again, the same crash repeats.

[image]

Comment: Did check the storyboard for any outlet / action that references `info`? IB is pretty bad in hunting these problems.

Comment: good point.  I did try searching for references to `info` but to no avail...

Comment: How about opening the `.storyboard` file in a text editor like Sublime or BBEdit and search through the XML?

Comment: I was hoping you're right.  But there's no `info` in the XML

Comment: Look at the stack trace from the crash. What's trying to call `info:`?

Comment: FYI you should be calling super on your `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` functions

Comment: of course.  how could i missed that...

Comment: Did the calls to `super` fix the issue? If so, post that as an answer.

Comment: calling `super` did not fix the issue.  still crash on upon first install.